# If Sam's age is twice the age Kelly was two years ago, Sam's age in four years will be how many times Kelly's age now?

Tags: recreational-mathematics

1. If Sam's age is twice the age Kelly was two years ago, Sam's age in four years will be how many times Kelly's age now?

(A) .5

(B) 1

(C) 1.5

(D) 2

(E) 4

So say at -2 years Sam's age is 12 and Kelly's age is 6. Add one to each year Sam passes.

-2 = 12

-1 = 13

0 = 14 (this would be the present year)

1 = 15

2 = 16

3 = 17

4 = 1

In four years, Sam will be 18 years old. With the same process with Kelly:

-2 = 6

-1 = 7

0 = 8

Kelly is now 8 years old. 18/8 is 2.25, which is not part of the answer choice, and the answer is apparently D) 2. What did I do wrong?

Comment: The first sentence compares Sam's age NOW with Kelly's age two years ago, not Sam's age two years ago with Kelly's age two years ago (what you calculated).

Comment: Wow I can't believe I just misunderstood the question. Thanks, makes sense now that I reread the prompt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $S$ denote Sam's age now, and let $K$ denote Kelly's age now.

$(1)$: We are given that Sam's **current age** is twice the age Kelly was $2$ years **ago**, so we have that $$S = \text{twice}\left(\text{Kelly's age 2 years ago}\right)\tag{1}$$

$(2)$ We are also asked to determine what multiple $x$ of $K$ will be equal to Sam's age **4 years from now**: $$\text{When will}\;xK\;\text{equal}\; S+ 4\quad ?\tag{2}$$

So we need to determine which of the given values for $x$ makes the following system "**match**":

$$S = 2(K - 2) \iff S = \color{blue}{\bf 2}K - 4\tag{1}$$

$$S + 4 = xK \iff \;\;S = \color{blue}{\bf x}K - 4\tag{2}$$

Now, what value must $\color{blue}{\bf x}$ be to make $\color{blue}{\bf 2}K - 4 = \color{blue}{\bf x} K - 4$?

Comment: @Amzoti It formats pretty quickly when you use it often enough.

Comment: $\color{blue}{+1}$

Answer (score 3):

Let $S$ be Sam's current age, and let $K$ be Kelly's current age. Then $K-2$ is Kelly's age two years ago, so the statement

> Sam's age is twice the age Kelly was two years ago

means that
$$S=2(K-2).$$
Applying the distributive property, this becomes
$$S=2K-4.$$
Thus, in four years, Sam's age will be $S+4$, which is equal to $2K$.

Answer (score 1):

First, your mistake is in understanding the auestion. *that's written sam's age is twice of anita's before 2 years*. It means that **nowadays** his age is twice then the age anita had **before ywo years**. Nobody had given you that before h2 years the ratio of ages was twice.

---

Now, I'll suggest a way to solve it. let's assign sam's age today as $s$ and anita's age in $a$. we are given tht sam's age nowadays is twice the age of anita before two years. We can write it in equlation-form: $$s=2\dot(a-2)=2a-4$$. Now we are asked to calculate the radio between sam's age in 4 years (a.k.a $s+4$) and anita's age today ($a$), so the radio can be expressed after evaluation as $$\frac{s+4}{a}=\frac{2a-4+4}{y}=\frac {2y}{y}=2$$. that's I think the right answer also.

Answer (score 1):

Others did already answer what you did wrong. I just want to show you how you can solve this kind of question.

### Formalize question

$x := $"Age of Sam today"

$y := $"Age of Kelly today"

$t := $"Factor you're looking for"

$x, y \in \mathbb{N}, t \in \mathbb{R}_0^+$

I) $x = 2 \cdot (y-2)$

II) $x+4=t \cdot y$

### Calculate answer

I) in II): $2 \cdot (y-2)+4 = t \cdot y$

$\Leftrightarrow 2 \cdot (y-2+2) = t \cdot y$

$\Leftrightarrow 2 \cdot y = t \cdot y$

$\Leftrightarrow t = 2$